# CD rom cannot open any disc, it say to burn new disc

Tags: laptop, compact-disc, optical-drive

No disc can be read by the Fujitsu L series laptop's DVD R/W optical drive. Whenever a disc is inserted, it says to burn the disc even if it's not a blank disc.

OS is windows 7 ultimate.

What should be done to recover from this problem?

Comment: You might see this problem if all the disks you're trying are writeable ones, and they have not been properly "finalized".  Have you tried it with a regular non-writeable CDROM?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic symptom of a damaged optical disc drive.

You could try to clean the lens (there are special [lens cleaners](http://www.google.com/search?q=dvd+lens+cleaner&tbm=shop) for that), but you'll probably have to buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'd say the optical drive has had it. This is not a problem you would typically see caused by software or driver issues.

Do you only have a single optical drive in the system or have you installed ISO mounting tools or virtual drives? If so, just make sure you are attempting to open the physical disk ;-)

Comment: not installed any virtual drives